# How to use font awesome 5 installed via NPM

Tags: css, npm, font-awesome

I am not finding any documents for what to do next, I installed font-awesome into my project via *npm*:

```
$ npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts
```

But now what?
Can anyone point me to how to actually import or use it now?

Comment: There's a clarification in the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js#free)

Answer (score 19):

First install it using **NPM** :

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save-dev
```

Now you have two ways, one way is to embed the absolute **URL** within your **HEAD** section or if you working with something like **SASS(SCSS)**, You can import it in your **custom.scss** file like this :

1. First set an absolute path for **webfonts** (It has to be set before the *fontawesome.scss*) :

   ```
   $fa-font-path: "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/WebFonts" !default;
   ```
2. Then import **fontawesome.scss** :

   ```
   @import "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
   ```
3. Finally import regular, solid or light(pro version) of icon types :

   ```
   @import "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
   ```

After all you can assign **font-family** to these classes to work:

```css
.fa,.fas,.far,.fal,.fab {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

by Gulp

in a SCSS file

```
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims";
```

in gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist+'/assets/webfonts/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

// ------------ FONT-AWESOME --------------------//

```
    $fa-font-path: $fonts_path + 'font-awesome';
```

> @import
>   '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fontawesome';
>
> @import
>   '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fa-brands';
>
> @import
>   '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fa-regular';
>
> @import
>   '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts/scss/fa-solid';

Answer (score -1):

To use an npm module on your front-end you'll need to be doing some sort of transpiling with webpack, gulp, or grunt most likely.

Then at the entry point of your application before you write html/jsx/some other html-esque code you'll need to require or import the css file from the font-awesome npm module.

```
// es6/babel import
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

// browserify require statement if not using babel/es6
require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
```

For example heres a react app I made with webpack/babel and on the entry point file I import the css file from font-awesome: https://github.com/AkyunaAkish/akyuna_akish/blob/master/client/index.js

FYI: 
I used

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

Instead of the command you used. You may need to adjust the import/require statement file path to point to the main css file in your font-awesome node_module package if we have slightly different packages.

Comment: The `font-awesome` package only goes to version 4.7.0. You will need the package `@fortawesome/fontawesome` for version 5.

Comment: The question is about font awesome 5 not 4xx.