# Install Font Awesome 5 with NPM

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am working with Angular(6) application, and I am trying to use FA icons, and drop-down with no luck. I am successfully using FA(4) icons, like:

```
<i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
```

But `<i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>` is not working. I am using following command to install FA:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

This is from `package.json` in `node_modules` folder:

[image]

I can see `font-awesome.css`, but it says `Font Awesome 4.7.0` as shown below:

[image]

In `angular.json` file, I referenced FA:
`"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",`

I read a lot of posts like [How to use font Awesome 5 installed via NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103401/how-to-use-font-awesome-5-installed-via-npm)

What do I need to do else?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For version 5, you need following package `@fortawesome/fontawesome`. See installation [using package managers](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers).

**Using npm:**

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then reference either the `all.css` or `all.js` in the `<head>`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">
```

**Note:** Make sure the path is right, depends on where you installed the package from.

**OR** you can import the module in your js code.

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
```

**OR** if you are using Sass, you can import the module in `app.scss`.

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/<type>';
```

**Note:** Replace `<type>` with `solid`, `brands` or `regular` whatever type of icons you need.

---

Font Awesome has an official [Angular](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) component.

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-<type>-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

**Note:** Replace `<type>` with `solid`, `brands` or `regular` whatever type of icons you need.

---

You can also install [Vue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) and [React](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react) components.

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Comment: i just ran the command `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`, still under `node_modules` > `font-awesome.css` showing the version `4.7.` i tried to delete the folder before i ran `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`, and the icon ` <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>` is not showing

Comment: if i use the CDN suggested [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css) the icon is showing, but i really dont want to use it like that and prefer to use package manager.

Comment: It's showing 5.3.1 in my case.. What folders are being shown to you? When I downloaded, I got this stucture: "node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\css". And in css folder, when I open fontawesome.css file, it shows 5.3.1 in it.

Comment: Thanks, found the problem, and i have no clue why it is working like this, after runing the command `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` in `node_modules` these 2 folders are getting copied 1- `font-awesome` it's version 4.7.0,and also 2- `@fortawesome` version 5.3.1. why do you think that it happens? maybe i have an old dependency

Comment: just checked, and i have an old dependency for the version 4.7.0, so i referenced it by mistake :/ it was showed under `devDependencies` in `pckages.json`

Comment: I guess it would have made too much sense to PLAINLY state this fact on their website, +1!

Answer (score 16):

**For Font Awesome 4.7.0:**

It should work by simply doing:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

And adding:

`@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";`

...to your `styles.css` or `styles.scss`.

---

**For Font Awesome 5** use the official Font Awesome 5 angular component

```
npm add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm add @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

In your template:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faAlignJustify"></fa-icon>
</div>
```

In your typescript:

```
import { faAlignJustify } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export class MyComponent {
  faAlignJustify = faAlignJustify;
}
```

In the module of your component:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` change the `package.json` to refer

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can install fontawesome as a module in your js code.

Steps:

1. `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save`
2. in your javascript code import the `all.js` file as instructed at the very bottom of the instructions [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers).

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js';
```

- or -

```
require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

A stumbling block for me was the final part of their installation docs. It says to reference the **all.css** file in your head tag.

I did it incorrectly.

The right way to link to this is the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css">
```

Hope this helps!

---

This should get it working for you.
Also, I would recommend reinstalling the latest version of the npm package using the [FontAwesome guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)